# Как сравнить choiceBox с другим choiceBox?

Tags: java, javafx

Я делаю конвертер и мне нужно, чтобы я выбирал в одном choiceBox одну валюту, в другом другую и курс менялся. Сами choiceBox`ы у меня есть. Есть идеи как можно это реализовать?

```
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.geometry.Insets;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.control.*;
 import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;
 import javafx.css.*;
 import java.util.Random;

 public class Lolita extends Application {

 Stage window;
 String UAH = "UAH", RUB = "RUB", USD = "USD", EUR = "EUR";  
 public Label valueFrom1;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
 }

 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws  Error {
    window = primaryStage;
    window.setTitle("VALUE");
    GridPane gP = new GridPane();
    gP.setPadding(new Insets(15, 33, 33, 15));
    gP.setVgap(15);
    gP.setHgap(20);



    TextField valueFrom = new TextField();
    valueFrom.setPromptText("Value From");
    GridPane.setConstraints(valueFrom, 1, 0);

    Random n = new Random();
    double y = n.nextDouble()*5;
    y = Math.rint(100.0 * y) / 100.0;

    Label nameValue3 = new Label("Курс сейчас: ");
    Label nameValue4 = new Label(String.valueOf(y));

    GridPane.setConstraints(nameValue3, 0, 2);
    GridPane.setConstraints(nameValue4, 1, 2);


    ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>();

    choiceBox.getItems().addAll(USD, UAH, EUR, RUB);
    choiceBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
            (v, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("Ваш выбор 1 " + newValue));
    GridPane.setConstraints(choiceBox, 0, 0);

    ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox2 = new ChoiceBox<>();
    choiceBox2.getItems().addAll(USD, UAH, EUR, RUB);
    choiceBox2.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    choiceBox2.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
            (v, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println("Ваш выбор 2 " + newValue));
    GridPane.setConstraints(choiceBox2, 0, 1);

    Button choice = new Button("Применить выбор");
    choice.setOnAction(e -> {
        switch ("UAH"){
            case "UAH":
        }
    });

    Button loginButton = new Button("Конвертирование");
    double finalY = y;
    loginButton.setOnAction(e -> {
                try {
                    double k = finalY;
                    double v = (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(valueFrom.getText())))*k;
                    double b = v;
                    Label valueFrom1 = new Label(String.valueOf(b));
                    this.valueFrom1 = valueFrom1;
                    GridPane.setConstraints(valueFrom1, 1, 1);
                    gP.getChildren().add(valueFrom1);
                }catch(Exception e1){
                    System.out.println("Какая-то ошибка, хз");
                }catch (Error error) {
                    System.out.println("Kek");}
    });

    GridPane.setConstraints(loginButton, 0, 5);

    gP.getChildren().addAll(choice, choiceBox, choiceBox2, valueFrom, nameValue3, nameValue4, loginButton);

    Scene scene = new Scene(gP, 500, 230);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();
}
```

}

Comment: постарайтесь выставлять только тот код, который необходим. Сам пакет указывать не обязательно, т.к. это важно только в вашем проекте

Answer (score 0):

Можно составить таблицу с курсом валют;
Например, вида

```
    UAH RUB USD EUR
UAH  1  1.5  2   3
RUB  4   1   6   7
USD  8   9   1   11 
EUR  12  13  14   1
```

это можно организовать через двумерный массив (неожиданно)

```
//список валют, для удобства оформленный в ArrayList
String[] currenciesArray = {UAH, RUB, USD, EUR};
ArrayList<String> currencies = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(currenciesArray));
//собственно, таблица
float[][] exchangeRateTable = {
    {1, 1.5f, 2, 3},
    {4, 1, 6, 7},
    {8, 9, 1, 11},
    {12, 13, 14, 1}
};//курс валюты по отношению к самой себе всегда = 1
```

получить курс таким образом будет довольно несложно:

```
//при выборе пользователем нового значения..
choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((v, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    //..получаем значение соседнего бокса
    String anotherSelected = choiceBox2.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    //..получаем порядковые номера валют в таблице
    int firstCurrencyIndex = currencies.indexOf(newValue);
    int secondCurrencyIndex = currencies.indexOf(anotherSelected);

    //..получаем курс для выбранных валют
    float exchangeRate = exchangeRateTable[secondCurrencyIndex][firstCurrencyIndex];

    //..выводим результат
    nameValue3.setText(exchangeRate+"");
});
```

Comment: p.s. я написал слушатель только для первого бокса, но для второго принцип тот же